# sed/awk: convertion of multi-column data

Tags: sed, awk

I am operating with multi-column data file procuded by some AWK script:

```
# output.csv
lig12, dG(rescored)
1, 0.596625
2, 1.05873
3, 1.11285
4, 0.697402
```

I need to modify this output.csv to one line format, containing: the first column of the firt line (lig12), the minimal value detected in the second column (among all lines, here it is 0.596625) as well as its corresponded ID number from the first column (here it is 1):

```
lig12, 0.596625 (1)
```

what combination of sed/awk may be useful, which can be pipped to my initial AWK script produced output.csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F ', ' '
NR==1 { coltitle=$1 }
NR==2 { min=$2; id=$1 }
NR>3 && $2<min { min=$2; id=$1 }
END { print coltitle FS min" ("id")" }
'
```

Output:

```
lig12, 0.596625 (1)
```

Comment: Thank you! it works OK with one CSV however if I pipe it to another AWK script which produce several logs shown above with the intension to process all the filles at once and save info for each csv in a new line, it does the job only for the first CSV ...

Comment: @HotJAMS: This information is not part of the question. Please read and comply with the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept your response ! And yes probably I will create a new topic regarding my case ! Cheers